# Name of files opened by a process in window?

Tags: python, c, windows, filesystems, windows-api-code-pack

How to print name of file open by some process (PID) in window? Or All Processes (PID) currently open a file.
    **Process Explorer** is a utility works for same. **But how does it work not mentioned?**
    Any */proc filesystem* kind of thing present in windows?

```
Can we read any Window's Registry?  
I wants to write a programming code And I rarely work on windows.
```

Got two solutions in Python:
    1.  import psutil
    2.  import win32api, win32con, win32process

But it is still a question to me!
    1. How does these libraries works?
    2. Any register, memory or virtual file system keeps this information?

> If its possible in window, **Why this information not present in TasK-Manager?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is the platform independent solution in python.

```
   import psutil
   p = psutil.Process(os.getpid()) # or PID of process
   p.open_files()
```

So i refer you [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) package it has too good functions for getting information on running processes

Comment: Will work on window?..Can you answer me how does psutil work?

Comment: "cross-platform process and system utilities module for Python" this is what psutil says. Work for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get a filename from pid using the Win32 API:

```
import win32api, win32con, win32process

handle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid) #get handle for the pid
filename = win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(handle, 0) #get exe path & filename for handle
```

This works on windows only (obviously).

Comment: Check out [Python for Windows](http://www.python.org/getit/windows/) for python versions that ship with the Win32 API bindings, or the [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) package. Win32 API is the definitive API for almost everything that happens in Windows, and this library provides bindings to those API functions.