# How to display uid, size and file's type?

Tags: c

I'm using gcc 32bit compiler. I used `stat()` function, but it is not giving the information about type of file. Is there any function or way to find all these?

Comment: Read [Name of files opened by a process in window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726218/name-of-files-opened-by-a-process-in-window) Python solutions.

Comment: Take a look at [this code snippet](http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:stat)

Comment: If you are in Linux read proc file system. (Also add tag)

Comment: What do you consider a file's type, please?

Comment: Type, as in, SHM or REG or socket...? Or the MIME type of a regular file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the st_mode member of struct stat.

From the stat(2) manpage:

```
     The status information word st_mode has the following bits:

 #define S_IFMT 0170000           /* type of file */
 #define        S_IFIFO  0010000  /* named pipe (fifo) */
 #define        S_IFCHR  0020000  /* character special */
 #define        S_IFDIR  0040000  /* directory */
 #define        S_IFBLK  0060000  /* block special */
 #define        S_IFREG  0100000  /* regular */
 #define        S_IFLNK  0120000  /* symbolic link */
 #define        S_IFSOCK 0140000  /* socket */
 #define        S_IFWHT  0160000  /* whiteout */
 #define S_ISUID 0004000  /* set user id on execution */
 #define S_ISGID 0002000  /* set group id on execution */
 #define S_ISVTX 0001000  /* save swapped text even after use */
 #define S_IRUSR 0000400  /* read permission, owner */
 #define S_IWUSR 0000200  /* write permission, owner */
 #define S_IXUSR 0000100  /* execute/search permission, owner */
```

sys/stat.h also provides the following defines for testing for file type.  You use them by passing the value of st_mode as a parameter:

```
#define S_ISBLK(m)      (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFBLK)     /* block special */
#define S_ISCHR(m)      (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFCHR)     /* char special */
#define S_ISDIR(m)      (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR)     /* directory */
#define S_ISFIFO(m)     (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFIFO)     /* fifo or socket */
#define S_ISREG(m)      (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFREG)     /* regular file */
#define S_ISLNK(m)      (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFLNK)     /* symbolic link */
#define S_ISSOCK(m)     (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFSOCK)    /* socket */
```

Answer (score 2):

*I used stat() function, but it is not giving the information about type of file.*

No, `stat()` in fact give you all you want about file.

```
struct stat {
    dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
    ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
    mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
    nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
    uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
    gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
    dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
    off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
    blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
    blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
    time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
    time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
    time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
};
```

So if you want the type of file , you can use `st_mode` information.

There are some marco you can use:  (all param is `st_mode`)

```
 S_ISREG(m)
is it a regular file?

S_ISDIR(m)

directory?

S_ISCHR(m)

character device?

S_ISBLK(m)

block device?

S_ISFIFO(m)

FIFO (named pipe)?

S_ISLNK(m)

symbolic link? (Not in POSIX.1-1996.)

S_ISSOCK(m)

socket? (Not in POSIX.1-1996.)
```

If you want learn more about `stat` . come [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html).

Answer (score 1):

`libmagic` is the library you'll want to look into for determining types of files without guessing based on extensions and that sort of stuff. It's what powers the common `file` command.

See: http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic

It'll (very quickly) inspect the file and return to you the actual mime type of the file, amongst other useful and interesting things.

Answer (score 0):

`uid` and `size` are returned by `stat()` as members `st_size` and `st_uid` of the `struct stat` filled by a succesful call to `stat()`.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

...

struct stat s = {0};
int result = stat("somefilename", &s);
if (-1 = result)
  perror("stat() failed");
else
{
  printf("%u\n", s.st_uid); /* Print uid. */
  printf("%ld\n", s.st_size); /* Print size. */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `file` command provided in c:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/file

From bash (but can be run inside a c program):

```
 $ file file.c file /dev/{wd0a,hda}
 file.c:   C program text
 file:     ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV),
```

Comment: And it's not provide by C. At least under Linux it is an external command: `/usr/bin/file`