# How to get list of files opened by a process in Windows?

Tags: c++, file, winapi, process

Windows tool `Handle.exe` created by Mark Russinovich ([link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx)) can be used to get the list of files opened by a process.

In my app I need the same feature - I need to know list of files opened by a different process.

How to implement this in my app?
Is it better to implement this in my app or launch `Handle.exe` as subprocess and parse output?
I briefly searched WinAPI docs and didn't found how to implement this...

For me it's not a problem to have an additional `.exe` file in the app folder. Main goal - everything should work fine on all Windows version since WinXP.

P.S.
Seems that this is very easy task in python [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726218/name-of-files-opened-by-a-process-in-window) ))

Comment: I think in c++ it's much the same as in the [2nd answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12726488/1413395) to that python question you have linked. Use these functions from the windows API.

Comment: This how to get the name of `.exe` file that has been launched. I need list of files opened by a process after it has been launched.

Comment: You can peek into python's [psutil implementation](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/psutil/arch/windows/process_handles.c#L32) (bsd-style license)